# parse cloud development on a windows computer - .NET required?

Tags: .net, parsing, mobile

i'm doing some parse development work, and i wanted to try out the cloud computing stuff that parse offers.

(Incidentally, my understanding of this is that its the code that will run before/after mobile app calls to the parse db, riiiiigh?)

I work on windows and i followed their instructions to get the parse client for dev work, and then i got this:

[image]

I'm not really sure what to do about this. I'm a  java guy, so .NET means nothing to me at all. Do i need to, um, get .NET? Does that mean visual basic something or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [.NET Framework, version 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) in order to use this application.